# Solution for AND/OR scenario with Linq possible?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a specific scenario which I want to solve using LINQ, but I'm stuck. I hope someone can give me an example or some pointers on how to solve this. I'm fairly new to LINQ.

I have two collections which contain objects of the same type (what kind of object doesn't really matter for the example).

Collection A contains 'A11' and 'A12'.

Collection B contains 'B11' and 'B12'.

I have a third collection that should contain a subset of the above elements according to the following rule:

```
(1 element of B AND (A11 OR A12))
```

So if I write out all possibilities this would become:

```
(B11 AND (A11 OR A12))

(B12 AND (A11 OR A12))
```

Ofcourse in my scenario those collections could become larger.

How would I solve this in LINQ to see if my collection C is correct according to that specific AND/OR rule?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. You want random element from `Collection A`?

Comment: Can you write some code examples, that you have tried? Do you want the resulting collection to be of the same type as first ones?

Comment: Could you describe your input and output and give a real example? It would be helpful for understanding your problem.

Comment: Do you mean 1 elemtn of B and 1 element of A? What would your logic look like if A contained more elements?

Comment: Yes, I mean 1 element of and 1 element of A. If A had more elements, the rule would be: (1 element of B AND (A11 OR A12 OR A13)). Etc.etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate it into two separate linq queries and combine them

```
if(collectionC.Intersect(collectionA).Any() && collectionC.Intersect(collectionB).Any())
```

This would be true when collectionC contains at least one from collectionA and at least one from collectionB

If you want more control on the count you can replace

```
.Any()
```

on each collection with

```
Count() > 0
```

More info on the intersect operation
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe#intersect1

Comment: Why did you use `Any` in the first query and `Count() > 0` in second? They do the same thing, but `Any()` is more efficient.

Comment: Missed it refactoring my answer (will update it now) :)

Any will be quicker, but count can be useful for when you want to have more than just n>=1